# anti-ample line bundles and global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a variety say over $\mathbf{C}$, $L$ a very ample line bundle and $\mathcal{E}$ a coherent sheaf on $X$.
It is well known  that $H^0(L^*)=0$. However, I'm curious what there can be said about $H^0(L^{-n}\otimes\mathcal{E})=0$, i.e. which sheaves $\mathcal{E}$ satisfy this vanishing for $n$ big enough?
I think one is tempted to think that must be zero for big $n$, but if e.g. $\mathcal{E}$ is of dimension $0$, for example the skyscraper sheaf of a point $\mathbf{C}_p$ then $H^0(L^{-n}\otimes \mathbf{C}_p)\cong \mathbf{C}$! What can there be said for maybe torsion-free sheaves $\mathcal{E}$?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always take $\mathcal{E}$ to be $\mathcal{E}' \otimes L$, then
$$
L^* \otimes \mathcal{E} \cong \mathcal{E}',
$$
so this can be arbitrary torsion sheaf, and you can't say anything about its $H^0$ in general.

EDIT. For the modified question, it is true that
$$
H^0(L^{-n} \otimes \mathcal{E}) = 0
\qquad
\text{for $n \gg 0$}
$$
unless $\mathcal{E}$ has 0-dimensional associated points (i.e., subsheaves supported on 0-dimensional subschemes). This follows from Serre duality and Serre vanishing.

Comment: thank you, yes that makes total sense of course! I edited my question slightly, do you still think there can be nothing said?

Comment: @Simonsays: I added an answer to the modified question.

Comment: ok great, I didn't see that right away: For a 0 dimensional sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ $H^0(L^{-n}\otimes\mathcal{E})=H^0(L^n\otimes \mathcal{E}^*)^*$ by applying Serre duality on $\text{supp}(\mathcal{E})$. And the latter is non zero. makes sense now thank you !!